# Merge ALMOST identical data rows

Tags: google-refine

I have a large amount of data (UK & US Postal addresses) 100,000+, that contains duplicate or ALMOST identical data rows (with 5 columns)
in the near identical rows four out of the five columns have exact matches of data
for example:-


`AAAA BBBB CCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC 11.111 22.222
AAAA BBBB CCCCCC CCCCCCCC          11.111 22.222
DDDD EEEE FF FFFFF FFFFF FFFFFFFFF 33.33  44.444
DDDD EEEE FF FFFFF FFFFF           33.33  44.444
GGGG HHHH IIII IIIII IIIIIIII      55.555 66.666
GGGG HHHH IIII IIIII               55.555 66.666`


i am trying to use Google Refine to remove these duplicate (or near duplicate rows)
i just cant managed it
what i want to end up with is:-



`AAAA BBBB CCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC 11.111 22.222
DDDD EEEE FF FFFFF FFFFF FFFFFFFFF 33.33  44.444
GGGG HHHH IIII IIIII IIIIIIII      55.555 66.666`


e.g. Discard the column with "Shorter" data length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing following steps -
1. sort on column 1
2. sort on column 2 
3. sort on column 4
4. sort on column 5
5. Reorder rows permanently (open on top)
now you would see that - all the rows sorted permanently.
do blank down on column 1.
Result would be -
    ===============================================================

> AAAA BBBB CCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC 11.111 22.222
>             BBBB CCCCCC CCCCCCCC          11.111 22.222
>       DDDD EEEE FF FFFFF FFFFF FFFFFFFFF 33.33  44.444
>            EEEE FF FFFFF FFFFF           33.33  44.444
>       GGGG HHHH IIII IIIII IIIIIIII      55.555 66.666
>            HHHH IIII IIIII               55.555 66.666

```
===================================================================
```

now select all the rows with blank on first column and delete all the rows.